# how to get formatted integer value in  javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my integer value

```
12232445
```

and i need to get like this.

```
12,232,445
```

Using prototype how to get this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this. I assume you want to format the number according to some local formatting rules?

Comment: yes.. i need formatted integer value

Comment: Okay, but *for what purpose exactly* and in what locale?  There are ready-made libraries for localization. It makes no sense to build a specific function for this specific locale. What if your application gets ported to some other locale in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var number = 12232445,
    value = number.toString(),
    parts = new Array;

while (value.length) {
    parts.unshift(value.substr(-3));
    value = value.substr(0, value.length - 3);
}

number = parts.join(',');
alert(number); // 12,232,445
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the cleanest solution, but it'll do:

```
function addCommas(n)
{
    var str = String(n);
    var result = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if((i - str.length) % 3 == 0)
            result += ',';
        result += str[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: for I/P `345` it returned `,345`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use, to format thousands separators and takes into account decimals if any:

```
function thousands(s) {
  var rx = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/,

    intDec = (''+s)
      .replace(new RegExp('\\' + $b.localisation.thousandSeparator,'g'), '')
      .split('\\' + $b.user.localisation.decimalFormat),

    intPart = intDec[0],
    decPart = intDec[1] || '';

  while (rx.test(intPart)) {
    intPart = intPart.replace(rx,'$1'+$b.localisation.thousandSeparator+'$2');
  }
  return intPart + (decPart && $b.localisation.decimalFormat) + decPart;
}
```

`thousands(1234.56)  //--> 1,234.56`

`$b.localisation` is a global variable used for the session.

`$b.localisation.thousands` can have the values `,` or `.` or a space. 
And `$b.localisation.decimalFormat` can have the values `,` or `.` depending on the locale of the user